# Modular Arithmetic and prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

With respect to the maths behind the Diffie Hellman Key exchange algorithm.

Why does:

(g<sup>a</sup> mod p)<sup>b</sup> mod p = g<sup>ab</sup> mod p

It might be fairly obvious, but what basic maths guarantees this? Why does the first modulo p expression disappear from the LHS in the expression on the RHS.

Apologies if it's not the right forum to ask it in. Maybe I should try the Information security stack Exchange forum instead.

Answer (score 3):

We can actually use the binomial theorem:

Observe that if we write $g^a=m+pk$, where $m\equiv g^a\mod p$, then $g^{ab}=(m+pk)^b=\sum_{n=0}^b \binom{b}{n} m^n(pk)^{n-b}\equiv m^b\mod p$, as every term except for the $n=b$ term will we divisible by $p$. Therefore, $(g^a\mod p)^b\mod p\equiv m^b\mod p$ and on the other hand $g^{ab}\mod p\equiv m^b$.

Comment: @PM2Ring Good catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It  reflects the definition of multiplication modulo $p$:
$$x\bmod p\cdot y\bmod p\begin{array}[b]{c}\text{def}\\[-1.5ex]{}={}\end{array}xy\bmod p$$

Comment: Can you advise on a decent resource to look at this further.  I've found (but it's not much help): http://www.di-mgt.com.au/multiplicative-group-mod-p.html

Comment: Perhaps [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) on the subject. It depends on your grade. One of my preferred books is Linsay Child's *A Concrete Introduction to Higher Algebra*. It's at the 2nd  year undergraduate level , and it covers many other subjects, but the chapters on congruence classes are readable at a lower level, in my opinion.

Comment: @Bernard This isn't by definition, you can actually prove it: $x=m_1+k_1p$ and $y=m_2+k_2p$, where $m_1,m_2\in\{0,...,p-1\}$, so $x\equiv m_1\mod p$ and $y\equiv m_2\mod p$. Then $xy=m_1m_2+m_1k_2p+m_2k_1p+k_1k_2p\equiv m_1m_2\mod p$.

Comment: @Ben S.I know, but you don't prove it, strictly speaking: you check it doesn't depend on the representatives in each class, *then* you can define &c.